# Error message when using tkinter in google cloud platform

Tags: tkinter, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to run my python script within google cloud platform and I get the following error when trying to open file dialog:

> _tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable

Is it possible to achieve that or is there an alternative?

Comment: You can't run tkinter in the cloud.

Comment: @bryan thanks a lot for the reply. So is there a way to retrieve the path name of a file?

Comment: Hi, @ChristianNana, which product we are talking about it? Remember that GCP is a platform with a bunch of products inside (GAE, GCE, GKE or Cloud Function).  Could you be more specific about it?

Comment: Hi! @hkanjih. The product in fact is GCE. I guess I am using the wrong product to deploy my application right?
Since I am new to this I started "accidentaly" with GCE and my flask app is reachable, but I am still having some trouble with tkinter making the app for other users not really usable, but on my local machine everything is fine. Tkinter seems to work. I can perform file dialog and select whatever I want, but when on GCE it seems not to work anymore and it seems that tkinter does not work in the cloud, what I was suspecting as well. I was wondering how I can get rid of that. Thanks!

Comment: Hi! I don't have knowledge about Tkinter, but I understood that is a Python library to develop desktop apps like "electronjs". Is that right? 
If I'm right, probably cloud is not the right place for your application, but if it is just for study purpose, you can create a GCE instance and install a GUI there. Follow some links to help you (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sT9JUL7q2uM&t=707s) and ( https://medium.com/google-cloud/graphical-user-interface-gui-for-google-compute-engine-instance-78fccda09e5c)

Comment: Hi @hkanjih! I believe as well that using tkinter in the cloud is not really appropriate and I need to find a way to make sure that my app goes online the way it is since I need the file dialog for my application and the only way I could do it up till now is to use tkinter. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

In case this comes up for anyone else.

What happened to me was I had used TRUE instead of `True`, and my IDE automatically added `import Tkinter`. Removing the import and using the right True value fixed my issue.